# Error Hard disk HDD

Tags: boot

[S.M.A.R.T Notification]

[image]

Please Help, do i need to replace the hard disk or i can fix it?

before this happen i delete all partitions on this hard disk and make a new one NTFS file system, i just want to make storage not for booting OS well this happening

And when i loaded live USB ubuntu, ubuntu can't booting just looping with some text dev/sda sector, bla bla bla

Please Help :(

Answer (score 0):

The hard drive has space reserved to reallocate bad sectors. Once that space gets fully utilized or when the hard errors exceed the percentage set in the firmware of the drive, You will get the error to "Backup and replace". That is your only safe option. It is inevitable that your hard drive will completely fail.

Detailed information about S.M.A.R.T. can be found at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

Comment: option? tell me please?